# After update Angular 6 to version angular 8 error found

Tags: angular, router, angular-router

I have updated Angular 6 to Angular 8. Now I am facing an error

> module not found in router. forEach module not found after updated.

```
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';
```

These are the versions of Angular and router:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
```

I want to resolve my issue.

Comment: Seems you imported from the src folder, which is not a good strategy. I guess angular removed it from lib. But version 8 is very old, what do you expect the forEach function is doing, you may should replace it by a better alternative.